# 'type' object is not subsrcriptable python

Tags: python, oop, object

i cant tell what this error is telling me it says the error is on line 64 of this code if possible can you please check too see if my code has additional errors thnx so much guys i tried multiple things and couldn't get it to work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AdamFeffer\triviacrack.py", line 93, in <module>
    QnA2()
  File "C:\Users\AdamFeffer\triviacrack.py", line 64, in QnA2
    if uanswer == quest[whichq].rA:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

import random
import time
# Flase = playerone true player 2
wt = False
score = 0
kg = True
kgt = True
playerov = False
class playerone(object):
        def __init__(self, name, score, victory):
                self.name = name
                self.score = score
                self.victory = victory
class playertwo(object):
        def __init__(self, name, score, victory):
                self.name = name
                self.score = score
                self.victory = victory
class quest(object):
    def __init__(self, q, a1, a2, a3, a4, rA):
        self.question = q
        self.answer1 = a1
        self.answer2 = a2
        self.answer3 = a3
        self.answer4 = a4
        self.realanswer = rA
### Questions ###
q1 = quest("The largest artery in the human body helps carry blood from the heart throughout the body. What is it?","Aorta", "your mom haha lol", "Jugular","Borta", 1)
q2 = quest("In the year 1900 in the U.S. what were the most popular first names given to boy and girl babies?", "William and Elizabeth", "Joseph and Catherine", "John and Mary","George and Anne", 3)
q3 = quest("When did the Liberty Bell get its name?", "when it was made, in 1701", "when it rang on July 4, 1776", "in the 19th century, when it became a symbol of the abolition of slavery", " none of the above", 3)
#################
#questoin arrays
questions = [q1, q2, q3]
qt = ["science", "history", "sports", "entertainment", "art"]
def QnA():
        global kg
        global oneplayer
        global score
        global player
        p = player
        whichq = random.randint(0, 4)
        print(questions[whichq].question)
        print(questions[whichq].answer1 + " (1)")
        print(questions[whichq].answer2 + " (2)")
        print(questions[whichq].answer3 + " (3)")
        print(questions[whichq].answer4 + " (4)") 
        uanswer = int(input("answer "))
        if uanswer == quest[whichq].realanswer:
                score = score + 1
                print ("YA NEXT QUESTION")
        else:
                print(p + "you didn't get it right")
                kg = False
def QnA2():
        global kgt
        global wt
        whichq = random.randint(0, 4)
        print(questions[whichq].question)
        print(questions[whichq].answer1 + " (1)")
        print(questions[whichq].answer2 + " (2)")
        print(questions[whichq].answer3 + " (3)")
        print(questions[whichq].answer4 + " (4)") 
        uanswer = int(input("answer "))
        if uanswer == quest[whichq].rA:
                if wt == false:
                        playerone.score = playerone.score + 1
                else:
                        playertwo.score = playertwo.score + 1
        if wt == True:
                wt = False
        else:
                wt = True
def timer():
        timer = 60
        while timer > 0:
                print (timer)
                timer = timer - 1
                time.sleep(1)
        print ("times up!!")
oot = int(input("(1) one player sudden death or (2) 2 player: "))
if oot == 1:
        oneplayer = True
        player = input("player name: ")
        while kg == True:
                QnA()
        print("sorry your score was " + (score) + "gg")
else:
        playero = input("player 1 name: ")
        playert = input("player 2 name: ")
        playerone = playerone(playero, 0, False)
        playertwo = playertwo(playert, 0, False)
        while kgt == True:
                QnA2()
```

Comment: don't use the 'global' keyword. it will just make it easier for you to introduce bugs. Pass arguments instead. That being said the problem is that you have a variable called questions but you accidentally typed 'quest' without the 'ions'

Comment: @ChadS. has good advice. Avoid `global` keyword. It has its place, but it can almost always be avoided and your code quality, readability, and maintainability will increase

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

Line 64: `if uanswer == questions[whichq].realanswer:`

**Whats wrong**

You are attempting to use `quest` which is a class instead of the `questions` list. `quest` can not be subscripted with `[]` but `questions` can, because it is a list.

In addition, you are trying to use `rA` which is an argument to the `__init__` function. You can not use this argument outside of `__init__`. Instead you need to use the member variable `realanswer` :)